# how to use model's serializer fields content?

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I  have a serializer like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

and a function like this:

```
def check (self , request):
        if unique('username' , 'email'):
            return True
        return False
```

how could I pass 'username' and 'email' content through the function?

Comment: Form the `request` object. I assume `check` is your viewfunction, so when you post your form and route your post request into your `check` method, you can easily get your data using `request.POST.get("username")`.

Comment: @Mahdi Sorkhmiri Are you trying to validate the `username` and `email` ?